# How to migrate to AndroidX in Android-Studio latest version?

Tags: flutter, androidx

When i click on migrate to androidX, it ask for backup as a zip file. While i click on (ok), after that nothing happens. I can't find from where i can  refactor it.

Comment: Can you share your gradle.properties file?

Answer (score 1):

In the android folder in your flutter app, there is gradle.properties file, include this

```
android.useAndroidX=true
```

then you're good to go

Comment: is there any warning you're getting in the debug console?

Comment: no nothing at all. After saving file  as backup as zip file it does nothing.